# Connecting Rasa Open source with Airy for Human Handoff

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I am working with Rasa chatbot version 3.1, I am trying to add feature like human handoff Agent with the help of connectors in rasa.

I am not clear in the following rasa documentation(https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/custom-connectors).

I would like to make some clear idea about following
[Airy->connnectors->Rasa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QepPV.png)
I dont know what are the values should be in the above image.